# How to add to an ArrayList <Student> students from a file but how do I add it if it is from another subclass? E.g: Unit_Common?

Tags: java

I am trying to add to ArrayList <Student> students by reading from a file, but I am stuck trying as the file is containing data which is from another subclass for example Unit. I could not call the method defined in the Unit class as the ArrayList is from Student class but the file has data on another class called Units.

```
public void addArrayList()
{
    //scanner object
    Scanner readUnit = null;
    //try block
    try{
        //open file for common and major student
        Scanner in  = new Scanner(new File("UnitInfo.txt"));
        while(in.hasNext())
        {
            String common = in.nextLine();
            String[] parts = common.split(" ");
            String enroltype = parts[0];
            String unitID = parts[1];
            int unitLevel = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
            Double assign1 = Double.parseDouble(parts[3]);
            Double assign2 = Double.parseDouble(parts[4]);
            Double weeklyPrac = Double.parseDouble(parts[5]);
            Double finalExam = Double.parseDouble(parts[6]);
            students.add(new Unit_Common(enroltype,unitID,unitLevel,assign1,assign2,weeklyPrac,finalExam));
```

I tired parsing method but it says no suitable constructor found. The expected output should be adding to the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

As per your error you would probably need to define below constructor in the Unit_Common class.

```
Unit_Common(String enroltype, String unitID, int unitLevel, Double assign, Double assign2, Double weeklyPrac, Double finalExam)){
Intialize the class variables here... 
}
```

Please Note: I am assuming that Unit_Common extends Students class. Thus for calling Unit_Common class method from the Arraylist you would have to cast student to Unit_Common.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, Unit_Common is an extension of another parent class called Unit. I am trying to call the methods in the Arraylist Student in the client class. How do I cast student to Unit_Common?